# Making a dropdown menu using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out what is a good approach to accomplish a dropdown menu that opens when a user clicks on a `div` which functions as a button and hides when the user click again on it. The style in my CSS sheet is set as `display: none`. and this is as far as i've gone:

```js
var xx = document.getElementById('dropdown-Container');

if (xx.display.style = 'none') {
  xx.addEventListener('click', function showMenu() {
    document.getElementById('dropdown-Container').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    xx.style.display = 'none';
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<div type="button" id="dropdown-Container">
  <a class="dropdown1" href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a class="dropdown1" href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a class="dropdown1" href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
<a href="#contact">Search</a>
</div>
```

The menu is hiding properly but when the user clicks on it, it's not opening up as I wish.

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are multiple errors in JS

Comment: Typo: `xx.display.style` should be `xx.style.display`

Comment: How can you click on something that's hidden?

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake in the code by placing the if statement above the event listener. Use it like this.

```
var menu = document.getElementById('yourDropdownMenuIdHere');
var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown-Container');

menu.addEventListener('click', function showMenu(){
    if( dropdown.style.display = 'none' ) {
       dropdown.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        dropdown.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Accessibility Issue: A div is not supposed to be used as a button for handling click. You can use a button tag instead

Comment: How can you click on something if its style is `display: none`?

Comment: Edit: Yes, The click listener should be attached to the menu that is always visible in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You need a double-equals in the 'none' comparison, at the very least.